# Can't Understand the following R language line

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join

```
data %>% select(gid,id, type, idtype, sourcenode, ctime, car) %>% distinct() -> final

final %>% group_by(gid) %>% mutate(count = n()) %>% distinct() -> final

final %>% left_join(car, by ="car") -> final
```

The above lines are from a `R` script. I am not able to understand what these lines actually means.
I have tried to follow a lot of resources, but I am still not sure about these lines.
Can someone help me understand all these 3 lines ?

Comment: Try to execute it step-by-step and see what changes does it make in the data. Start 1) `data` 2) `data %>% select(gid,id, type, idtype, sourcenode, ctime, car)` 3) `data %>% select(gid,id, type, idtype, sourcenode, ctime, car) %>% distinct()` and so on.

Comment: Have a look at the `dplyr` package. Use R help to get what the functions are doing

Comment: Actually, my R environment is not setup, it is throwing me some kind of exception related to the RMySQL package, which i am trying to fix from the last 3 days and no progress in that too.

Comment: Current question is off topic - read the manuals. `"some kind of exception related to the RMySQL"`... ask as new question with more details, errors, warnings, sessioninfo, etc.

Comment: Both "this question" (understanding code) and "should be a new question" (RMySQL error) would benefit from a more reproducible question. Since we don't know what your `data` looks like, there is speculation. (My guess is that it is a `dbplyr` object, which might explain the RMySQL error. If the database connection has gone stale, then you're going to need to reconnect. If you were perhaps on-campus or in the office when you started the work, then continued elsewhere, then network connectivity might be an issue.)

Answer (score 2):

The comments are right and there should particular questions on particular issues. Either way, here a few things that might help in understanding the code.

`%>%` is the so-called pipe-operator and can be read as "then".

```
data %>% select(gid,id, type, idtype, sourcenode, ctime, car) %>% distinct() -> final
```

would translate to

take `data` then select columns `gid,id, type, idtype, sourcenode, ctime, car` then find all distinct combinations and assign them to the variable `final`

This code is using the `dplyr` package (or more broader the `tidyverse`). Hadley Wickham and Garrett Grolemund wrote a great book on this, which is online available [here](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/).

Comment: Good answer. Of note, the forward arrow is not very common in R but some users like to use them at the end of a pipeline. You probably would see more often `final <- data %>% select(...)`, or even `final = data %>% select(...)`.

Comment: @DanChaltiel is right. I would not recommend using `->` and actually consider this "suboptimal" coding style. Why? If you put assign operators in the front (`a <- 1:5`) then one can easily see where a variable is changed or created - on the contrary you would have to skim the entire code to find these assignments (`->`).

Comment: If we are at recommendations, I'd even advocate for `=`, as `x<-3` could be read as "put 3 in variable x" or as "x is lesser than -3" depending on the context, whereas `x=3` is rather unambiguous.